# Elastic Beanstalk Log Path Not Updating When Docker Container Changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

When I launch an ElasticBeanstalk instance with docker I get log streaming to cloudwatch in a group named `/aws/elasticbeanstalk/{app_name}/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/stdouterr.log`. If I push an update to this beanstalk app the docker container is terminated, and a new docker container is launched in it's place. The issue is that when this happens, logs are being generated under the new docker container id, but they are not streaming to cloudwatch.

How can I update my docker container and continue streaming logs to cloudwatch?

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to your log messages having the same hash so the Cloud Watch Agent is getting confused. See [No logs appear on Cloudwatch log group for elastic beanstalk environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57481837/no-logs-appear-on-cloudwatch-log-group-for-elastic-beanstalk-environment)