# No logs appear on Cloudwatch log group for elastic beanstalk environment

Tags: node.js, docker, logging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an elastic beanstalk environment, which is running a docker container that has a node js API. On the AWS Console, if I select my environment, then go to Configuration/Software I have the following:

- Log groups: **/aws/elasticbeanstalk/my-environment**
- Log streaming: **Enabled**
- Retention: **3 days**
- Lifecycle: **Keep after termination**.

However, if I click on that log group on the Cloudwatch console, I have a *Last Event Time* of some weeks ago (which I believe corresponds to when the environment was created) and have no content on the logs.

Since this is a dockerized application, Logs for the server itself should be at **/aws/elasticbeanstalk/my-environment/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/stdouterr.log**.
If I instead get the Logs directly from the instances by going once again to my EB environment, clicking "Logs" and then "Request last 100 Lines" the logging is happening correctly. I just can't see a thing when using CloudWatch.

Any help is gladly appreciated

Comment: Have you been redeploying your app ie: starting a new container? If so I think your question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57464585/elastic-beanstalk-log-path-not-updating-when-docker-container-changes

Comment: Yes seems related, but unfortunately no answer there. If I check out my CloudWatch log groups I have something like :

/aws/elasticbeanstalk/my-env/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/stdouterr.log

However if I pull the logs directly I observe the following:

/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/eb-"hexstring"-stdouterr.log

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to get around this problem.
So CloudWatch makes a hash based on the first line of your log file and the log stream key, and the problem is that my first line on the **stdouterr.log** file was actually an empty line!

After couple of days playing around and getting help from the good AWS support team, I first connected via SSH to my EC2 instance associated to the EB environment and you need to add the following line to the */etc/awslogs/config/beanstalklogs.conf* file, right after the "file=/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/*stdouterr.log*" line:

**file_fingerprint_lines=1-20**

With these, you tell the AWS service that it should calculate the hash using lines 1 through 20 on the log file. You could change 20 for larger or smaller numbers depending on your logging content; however I don't know if there is an upper limit for the value.

After doing so, you need to restart the **AWS Logs Service** on the instance.

For this you would execute:

- *sudo service awslogs stop*
- *sudo service awslogs start*

or simpler:

*sudo service awslogs restart*

After these steps I started using my environment and the logging was now being properly streamed to the CloudWatch console!
However this would not work if a new deployment is made, if the EC2 instance gets replaced or the auto scalable group spawns another.

To have a fix for this, it is possible to add log config via the *.ebextensions* directory, at the root of your application before deploying.

I added a file called *logs.config* to the newly created *.ebextensions* directory and placed the following content:

```
files:
  "/etc/awslogs/config/beanstalklogs.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    user: root
    group: root
    content: |
      [/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/stdouterr.log]
      log_group_name=/aws/elasticbeanstalk/EB-ENV-NAME/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/stdouterr.log
      log_stream_name={instance_id}
      file=/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/*stdouterr.log
      file_fingerprint_lines=1-20

commands:
  01_remove_eb_stream_config:
    command: 'rm /etc/awslogs/config/beanstalklogs.conf.bak'
  02_restart_log_agent:
    command: 'service awslogs restart'
```

Changing of course **EB-ENV-NAME** by my environment name on EB.

Hope it can help someone else!

Comment: Great job solving this as I also was having the same issues. Do your log statements contain timestamps? It was suggested to me to change my application logging config so log messages had a timestamp. Because any hashes will therefore always be different and you don't have to provide any extra Beanstalk logging configuration like you've done.

Comment: @kierans that would also solve the problem from what I know. The thing is that I am using a framework that by default outputs the first line of the logs as an empty line, so I am guessing this was the one compared by the AWS logs agent, and is why I had to rely on modifying the "file_fingerprint_lines"

Comment: @FaridHajnal shouldn't this config remove the existing logging setup in beanstalklogs.conf ?

Comment: This did not work for my NodeJS Single Docker Instance (Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.0.3) .

Comment: @ArielFrischer hello. I am using NestJs framework for my server application, which is also running on a single docker instance environment

Comment: @Farid Hajnal Hi, do you have a question? Also I'd like to add to my previous script that it didn't work because it caused a deployment error. I'm currently trying some fixes with AWS support team, if something works I'll report as an answer below.

Answer (score 7):

For 64 bit Amazon Linux 2 the setup is slightly different.

For the delivery of log the AWS CloudWatch Agent is installed in `/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent` and the Elastic Beanstalk configuration is in `/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/beanstalk.json`. It is set to log the output of the container assuming there's a file called `stdouterr.log`, here's a snippet of the config:

```
{
  "file_path": "/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/stdouterr.log",
  "log_group_name": "/aws/elasticbeanstalk/EB-ENV-NAME/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/stdouterr.log",
  "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
}
```

However when I look for the `file_path` it doesn't exist, instead I have a file path that encodes the current docker container ID `/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/eb-e4e26c0bc464-stdouterr.log`.

This logfile is created by a script `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/eb-docker-log-start` that is started by the `eb-docker-log` service, the default contents of this file are:

```
EB_CONFIG_DOCKER_CURRENT_APP=`cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/.aws_beanstalk.current-container-id | cut -c 1-12`
mkdir -p /var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/
docker logs -f $EB_CONFIG_DOCKER_CURRENT_APP >> /var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/eb-$EB_CONFIG_DOCKER_CURRENT_APP-stdouterr.log 2>&1
```

To temporarily fix the logging you can manually run (replacing the docker ID) and then logs will start to appear in CloudWatch:

```
ln -sf /var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/eb-e4e26c0bc464-stdouterr.log /var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/stdouterr.log
```

To make this permanant I added an `.ebextension` to fix the `eb-docker-log` service so it re-makes this link so create a file in your source code in `.ebextensions` called `fix-cloudwatch-logging.config` and set it's contents to:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/eb-docker-log-start" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      EB_CONFIG_DOCKER_CURRENT_APP=`cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/.aws_beanstalk.current-container-id | cut -c 1-12`
      mkdir -p /var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/
      ln -sf /var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/eb-$EB_CONFIG_DOCKER_CURRENT_APP-stdouterr.log /var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/stdouterr.log
      docker logs -f $EB_CONFIG_DOCKER_CURRENT_APP >> /var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/eb-$EB_CONFIG_DOCKER_CURRENT_APP-stdouterr.log 2>&1
commands:
  fix_logging:
    command: systemctl restart eb-docker-log.service
    cwd: /home/ec2-user
    test: "[ ! -L /var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/stdouterr.log ] && systemctl is-active --quiet eb-docker-log"
```

Comment: This worked for me! as a point of clarification, I placed the `.ebextensions` directory in the project directory, not in the `.elasticbeanstalk` directory.

Comment: I've removed the reference to elasticbeanstalk, this is because of how I arrange project locally, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Ok some time it appears that AWS fixed this and with "Amazon Linux 2/3.2.3" it's no longer needed. I don't know exactly when it was fixed.

Comment: Whenever it was fixed, they've added a `*` to the ' "file_path": "/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/*stdouterr.log",' . Still would be cool to know where they document fixes like this though.